# Replace string in perl script

Tags: perl

I have a code:

```
my $orgstr = "\$map_remain{3}{1}=\"\${prefix}_123456\";";
my $cell   = "\${prefix}_123456";
$orgstr =~ s/$cell/abc/;
print "new str: $orgstr\n";
```

i want to replace **${prefix}_123456** to **abc** but this

```
$orgstr =~ s/$cell/abc/;
```

does not do , i dont know why, pleae anyone can help this ?

Comment: You need to quote regex meta characters in the pattern since you want to match a literal. One way to do that is to use the [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) construct "\Q...\E"  like this:  `$orgstr =~ s/\Q$cell\E/abc/`